# Listen to ARP broadcast in Java

Tags: java, networking, packet-capture, arp

Can someone please guide me on listening to ARP broadcasts in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JpCap](https://github.com/jpcap/jpcap/) to listen to ARP Packets.

> Jpcap is a Java library for capturing
>   and sending network packets.
>
> Using Jpcap, you can develop
>   applications to capture packets from a
>   network interface and
>   visualize/analyze them in Java. You
>   can also develop Java applications to
>   send arbitrary packets through a
>   network interface.
>
> Jpcap has been tested on Microsoft
>   Windows (98/2000/XP/Vista), Linux
>   (Fedora, Mandriva, Ubuntu), Mac OS X
>   (Darwin), FreeBSD, and Solaris.
>
> Jpcap can capture Ethernet, IPv4,
>   IPv6, **ARP/RARP**, TCP, UDP, and ICMPv4
>   packets.
>
> Jpcap is open source, and is licensed
>   under GNU LGPL.

Edit: The last commit on JPCAP in github is from 9 years ago.

Comment: Yup - it will work on anything that supports libpcap/Winpcap, as it's basically a Java binding for that.